# dynamic id for li tag

Tags: jsp, el

How can I create a dynamic id of li tag using the foodInfo which is set to `c:set`?

```
<c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${selectedIngredientsList}">
        <c:set var="foodInfo" value="${food.foodItemId}~${food.foodCategoryId}~${food.foodName}~${food.foodPortionName}"/>    
        <ul>
            <li id="??"><c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>
            </li>
        </ul> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can directly assign the values in the id attribute of the `<li>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used like below to assign dynamic id with the prefix that I want to use.

```
<li id="my_${foodInfo}">
```

Comment: Note that `~` is an illegal character in HTML ID attribute. Rather use `id="item_${food.foorItemId}"` or maybe even `id="item_${i.index}"`.