# How to select element if I don't know its id

Tags: javascript, jquery

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017817/dynamic-id-for-li-tag) I have learned how to set dynamic id for the following code snippent -

```
<c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${selectedIngredientsList}">
        <c:set var="foodInfo" value="${food.foodItemId}"/>    
        <ul>
            <li id="??"><c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>
            </li>
        </ul> 
</c:forEach>
```

I can set dynamic id like this (according to [kitokid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751689/kitokid)'s answer) - `<li id="my_${foodInfo}">`. This trick work for me.
But if I want to get the id from javascript by using id selector how can I achieve this? For static id we can write $('#myId'). Since the id here is dynamic how can I catch the id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not standard HTML.

Comment: This is not ment to be. It actually is JSF

Comment: For HTML/JS questions if server side code is not relevant, it's recommended to post rendered HTML code, not initial server templates.

Comment: @DavidSherret - isn't it obvious my point was that the the tags related to this should be updated to reflect there is a server rendering involved?

Comment: @dfsq it's relevant in this case becuase he's wondering how to work with dynamic ids.

Comment: Also trying to incorporate your own JS in JSF is sometimes very complicated!

Comment: @PlantTheIdea sorry, it wasn't because the post was edited before I made my comment so I didn't see it was originally tagged with `html`

Comment: @DavidSherret I don't think it's relevant to *this* question. The question is "how to select element if I don't know its id". However since OP is not sure about the best approach, it's doesn't hurt to have JSF here.

Comment: @dfsq thanks. I think "how to select element if I don't know its id" is the more appropriate title for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other CSS selectors. For example you can bind click event on parent `UL` element and then handle click event like this:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert( this.id ); // get click id
});
```

or

```
$('li').click(function() {})
```

will also bind click event to each `LI` element.

So you don't have to know id of the element to find this element and bind event to it.